# The precendence of operators in Java is not applied

Tags: java, operators, operator-precedence

I have this piece of code and according to this page [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html)
The below output should by right give me, 98.24 but this is giving me 68.8, what is that I am missing here?

```java
public class Qn1 
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
       double cel = 36.8;
       double fah = ((9 / 5 )* cel) + 32;
       System.out.println(cel + "deg C =" + fah +" deg F");
    }
}
```

Comment: How did you calculated that?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use `9.0 / 5` instead of `9 / 5` in bracket.

`9 / 5` is integer division and its value is `1`. And hence the result. You just need to make one of the *numerator* or *denominator* a *double / float* value to enforce *floating-point division*.

```
((9 / 5 ) * cel) + 32  = (1 * 36.8) + 32 = 68.8
```

And what you need is: -

```
((9.0 / 5 ) * cel) + 32  = (1.8 * 36.8) + 32 = 66.24 + 32 = 98.24
```

Answer (score 1):

```
double fah = ((9.0 / 5 )* cel) + 32;
```

Comment: You have given the man a fish rather than taught him how to fish

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you are not using `double` but `int`. Use

```
double fah = ((9d / 5d) * cel) + 32d;
```

Answer (score 1):

Use at least one `double` operand:

```
double fah = 9.0 / 5 * cel + 32;

double fah = 9 / 5.0 * cel + 32;

double fah = 9.0 / 5.0 * cel + 32;
```

These three ways are valid and note that parenthesis are unnecessary.

Comment: If you have considered removing the unnecessary parenthesis, then you can remove all of them. None of them are needed.

Answer (score 0):

`9` is integer, so is `5` : so `9/5` is using integer division, meaning it results into 1 (integer) and not 1.8 (float)

```
1*36.8 +32 = 68.8
```

Answer (score 0):

9 / 5 in integer arithmetic is 1